# Calling clear() on a vector of shared_ptr. Will memory be freed?

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have a `std::vector` member of `boost::shared_ptr` to objects of class `Foo` inside a class.
A function `SetData()` adds a pointer to a new object of `Foo` to the vector. The contructor of `Foo` makes an internal copy of the data pointed to by `pData`.
Now when I call my `Reset()` function, will all the memory actually be freed?

```
class myClass()
{
 void SetData(char* pData, size_t nSize)
 {
   boost::shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo(new Foo(pData, nSize));
   mVector.push_back(pFoo);
 }

 void Reset()
 {
   mVector.clear();
 }

private:
    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Foo>> mVector;


};
```

Comment: I have another question, what if you do not call clear and vector goes out of scope. Does memory get clear for all smart pointers within vector?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I have another question, what if he does not call clear and vector goes out of scope. Does memory get clear for all smart pointers within vector?

Answer (score 6):

> will all the memory actually be freed?

It rather depends on what you're asking. On the surface of it, **yes.**

The entire purpose of smart pointers is that they manage memory for you, and the entire purpose of shared pointers it that the thing they point to is automatically freed when no more shared pointers point to it.

When you clear the vector, the shared pointers it contains are destroyed, and this action automatically de-allocates any encapsulated objects with no more shared pointers referring to them.

Now, does that free *all* memory? Not necessarily. We have no idea what `Foo` does; if you didn't properly implement RAII in it, then it's possible that `Foo` leaks memory and the answer becomes **no**.

Comment: The data that was initially pointed to by `char* pData` can't really be commented on. All told, bad code, what can you do? Start again?

Comment: @thecoshman: Yes I believe I addressed that with "It's impossible to say"

Comment: indeed, posted comment then refreshed to see your edit... but of course, SO doesn't want to publicise that you edited...

Comment: I have another question, what if he does not call clear and vector goes out of scope. Does memory get clear for all smart pointers within vector?